# SQL query performance- ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an update query which is taking 15 hrs to complete in the production server. What modifications can I do to make it run faster.

```
UPDATE pos
SET pos.is_pub = 1
FROM A pos
WHERE pos.is_pub <> 1
and s_type <= (
        SELECT TOP 1 month
        FROM B with(nolock)
        )
    AND isnull(is_pub, 0) <> 1
    AND isnull(is_adj, 0) <> 1
```

here 'type' and 'month' are actually integers having number of months as the values.

Comment: Odd condition: `s_type <= month`... (_apples and oranges_)

Comment: How many rows are being updated?

Comment: Why `with(nolock)`? You know what that does, *right*..? And why a `TOP 1` with no `ORDER BY`? You're happy with a random value for `month` with the double added problem of `WITH (NOLOCK)`? This seems like you're intentionally asking for odd behaviour.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0):

Start by moving the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE pos
    SET pos.is_pub = 1
FROM A pos CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 1 month
      FROM B with (nolock)   -- very strange, no `order by`
     ) b
WHERE pos.is_pub <> 1 AND
      pos.s_type <= b.month AND  -- very strange, comparing "type" to "month"
      (is_adj is null or is_adj <> 0);
```

Given this, there is not much that indexes can do because of the `WHERE` conditions.  Perhaps you are updating essentially all rows in the table, which can be quite expensive.  It is often cheaper to re-build the table rather than update it.

Comment: It gonna be a shot in the dark without a clear description.